# Creating blocks in Grasshopper dynamically

Tags: udp, rhino, grasshopper

What I have: When my device moves, point data is sent to grasshopper via UDP.

What I want: Visualize the path in rhino/grasshopper based on the incoming points.

Is it possible to create the points / blocks dynamically?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: have u tried anything??

Comment: Well, more or less. I did not find any way to create points from the incoming text messages. That is my problem ;)

Comment: Please remove the rhino tag, as this question doesn't relate to Rhino (but relates to rhino3d)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the timer component in Grasshopper to continuously update your UDP receiver. Anything downstream from there, such as a spline through a list of points, will be redrawn with every change.

Answer (score 0):

So far it is unclear what is it that you have a problem with exactly. If you have trouble with interpreting incoming text messages, try text split component to break down your message into XYZ point coordinates and then use construct point component.
If the problem is with storing the points, try data recorder component.